# How to config Lucee with IIS server in windows 10

Tags: lucee

I will ready have some site in IIS, I also need add some coldfusion sites there.

I just install Lucee, how to make lucee handle cfml pages in IIS.

I need know what I need setup in Lucee and IIS

Thanks for help

Answer (score 2):

First step: You need to turn on the 'role and features" in Windows control panel in order to add the IIS role/feature to windows 10. How to do it you can find here:
https://windowsjet.com/how-to-enable-iisinternet-information-services-in-windows-10-403/

Second step: Follow the instructions in the Lucee documentation with this video guide:
https://docs.lucee.org/guides/installing-lucee/windows/installing-lucee-on-windows-2019-with-installer-quick-video-guide.html

The above guide is about Windows Server 2019, but I've done it that way on Windows 10 also and it worked.